# Fixing an object $Y$ defines a contravariant functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow$ Sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Say we fix an object $Y$, and then consider the assignment $(\mathcal{C}^{op})_0 \rightarrow$ Sets that sends $X$ to $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y)$. How can I show that this defines a contravariant functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow$ Sets? In other words, I'm being asked to define the morphisms.

Is the point just that we can fix $Y$, then that $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y) = \hom_{\mathcal{C}^{op}}(Y, X)$? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: What is $(\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}})_0$?

Comment: $(\mathcal{C}^{op})_0 = \mathcal{C}_0$, or the objects of $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

One important point:  The assignment $X \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ defines a (covariant) functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{Sets}$, that is, a contravariant functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Sets}$.  Think about how we may map the arrow $X \stackrel{f}{\to} X'$ to an appropriate arrow (which we will call $f^*$):
$$
f^* : \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X',Y) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y). 
$$
In other words, given a typical morphism $X' \stackrel{g}{\to} Y$, can you think of a way to use $f$ to produce a morphism $X \stackrel{f^*(g)}{\to} Y$ ?  Once you make what amounts to the most straighforward or obvious choice, you may verify that the axioms for a functor are satisfied.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I was thinking to do precomposition, but I keep getting stuck trying to prove that $F(g \circ f) = F(g) \circ F(f)$. Doesn't something go wrong here?

$F(g \circ f) = h \circ g \circ f$ but $F(g) \circ F(f) = h \circ f \circ g$.

Comment: Recall, the functor goes from $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ to $\mathbf{Sets}$.... So you that means you should show $F(g \circ f) = F(f) \circ F(g)$, where $\circ$ is composition in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: If you still are unsure, draw an arrow diagram.  And if you're still stuck after that, I'd be happy to expand on my answer above.

Comment: Is it just the following: 

$F(g \circ f)(h) = (g \circ f)^*(h) = h \circ (g \circ f) = f^* \circ g^*(h) = F(f) \circ F(g) (h)$?

Comment: $F(g \circ f)(h) = h \circ (g \circ f) = (h \circ g) \circ f = F(g)(h) \circ f = F(f)( F(g)(h) ) = (F(f) \circ F(g))(h)$.  Therefore, since $h$ was arbitrary, $F(g \circ f) = F(f) \circ F(g)$.